# Michael Hart Tutorial Chapter 7 - PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "users" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I'm at the end of Chapter 7 [Michael Harl Rails Tutorial](http://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up) and having a problem when I execute `heroku run rake db:migrate`. It is saying 'users' does not exist. I've tried to reset the heroku database and then migrate but still the same error. Any ideas would be appreciated.See the full error trace included below.

Here is the migration file:

```
   class AddPasswordDigestToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        add_column :users, :password_digest, :string
      end
    end
```

And the schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150824215943) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
  end

end
```

and the user model:

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
                    format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

end
```

The full error trace:

```
 Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.1726
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Migrating to AddPasswordDigestToUsers (20150824215943)
   (1.0ms)  BEGIN
== 20150824215943 AddPasswordDigestToUsers: migrating =========================
-- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)
   (1.5ms)  ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "password_digest" character varying
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "password_digest" character varying
   (0.9ms)  ROLLBACK
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD "password_digest" character varying/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:473:in `block in log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:467:in `log'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:393:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:425:in `add_column'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:662:in `block in method_missing'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `block in say_with_time'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:632:in `say_with_time'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:652:in `method_missing'
/app/db/migrate/20150824215943_add_password_digest_to_users.rb:3:in `change'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/benchmark.rb:281:in `measure'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:188:in `within_new_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. At first tried `heroku pg:reset DATABASE` to no avail.
Then ran `heroku run rake db:reset` and then migrated succesfully